# CSS image in front of text

Tags: html, css, image, z-index

I am trying to place an ***image in front of text***, which is inside a div. Almost ever search for this brings results on how to put text in front of an image. This is not what I want to do.

In the following example I have a gif and tried using z-index: -1; in the CSS but this is not working.

The HTML

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  vertically-align: middle;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img width="100" height="100" src="http://bestanimations.com/Animals/Reptiles/Dinosaurs/dinosaur-animated-gif-6.gif" />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer lobortis aliquam eros, sed vehicula eros rhoncus eu. Cras bibendum rhoncus nisl, non venenatis enim interdum vel. Mauris sodales risus ac ex suscipit ultricies. Duis neque purus, auctor
  non magna vel, euismod posuere metus. Fusce sit amet tortor quis felis consectetur iaculis. Phasellus risus nibh, finibus lacinia porta a, sagittis quis orci. Integer feugiat sit amet diam sit amet accumsan. In at finibus eros, vitae dictum eros. Donec
  dignissim tellus id dui auctor convallis. Donec in faucibus eros, at ultrices felis. Vivamus eros augue, suscipit a dignissim et, efficitur nec nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean iaculis consequat neque, et placerat
  tellus mollis ac. Curabitur ut pulvinar neque, eu aliquam purus. Vestibulum imperdiet, orci eget molestie ultricies, est dui faucibus dui, et venenatis neque sem non lorem. In in massa condimentum, vulputate lacus vitae, posuere lorem. Nullam faucibus
  augue a dolor vestibulum, id efficitur augue aliquam. Fusce in ipsum aliquet, scelerisque augue ac, pretium urna. Nunc rutrum lacus vitae magna congue, vel finibus ligula sodales. Aenean vitae egestas lectus. Quisque ut pretium nunc. Curabitur id lectus
  est. Duis nulla elit, vestibulum vitae pulvinar sit amet, tristique ut leo. Curabitur finibus ipsum sit amet ante venenatis efficitur. Fusce molestie nibh nec nisi pretium finibus. Ut ullamcorper sapien sapien, ut dictum libero elementum et. Cras sapien
  augue, placerat vitae venenatis in, tempor sed enim. Nullam interdum, ante a pretium condimentum, ante lacus sollicitudin odio, at luctus lectus elit in mauris. Aenean a hendrerit neque, et porta ipsum. Maecenas tincidunt, eros eu auctor posuere, odio
  felis tincidunt leo, id pellentesque neque neque nec diam. Sed ac ante ac neque porta suscipit. Sed nec lacus ligula. Nunc maximus fermentum risus eget vehicula. Sed ac varius tortor. Fusce blandit mollis commodo. Quisque orci magna, consequat et orci
  at, consequat interdum arcu. Vestibulum vel iaculis magna, ut gravida enim. Nullam sollicitudin pharetra auctor. Mauris vulputate justo lorem, non aliquet elit cursus sed. Duis ultricies euismod diam, in rhoncus nisi auctor sit amet. Morbi dignissim
  fermentum sem, vel volutpat quam accumsan ut. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam quis lectus metus.
  <div>
  <div>
      I am a second div
  </div>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Well... your snippet is almost working now. If intention is to place dyno above text, you must use higher z-index. z-index:-1 places it at the bottom of the stack. Also, parent div should be relatively positioned...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just do this:

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

And, if you make the parent div relative:

```
div {
    position: relative;
}
```

You can move your image anywhere inside that text div:

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 30px;
    top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To trigger `z-index` you need to reset `position` to any valid value but `static`:

`absolute`:

```css
img,
span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
img {
  position:absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img width="100" height="100" src="http://bestanimations.com/Animals/Reptiles/Dinosaurs/dinosaur-animated-gif-6.gif" />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer lobortis aliquam eros, sed vehicula eros rhoncus eu. Cras bibendum rhoncus nisl, non venenatis enim interdum vel. Mauris sodales risus ac ex suscipit ultricies. Duis neque purus, auctor
  non magna vel, euismod posuere metus. Fusce sit amet tortor quis felis consectetur iaculis. Phasellus risus nibh, finibus lacinia porta a, sagittis quis orci. Integer feugiat sit amet diam sit amet accumsan. In at finibus eros, vitae dictum eros. Donec
  dignissim tellus id dui auctor convallis. Donec in faucibus eros, at ultrices felis. Vivamus eros augue, suscipit a dignissim et, efficitur nec nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean iaculis consequat neque, et placerat
  tellus mollis ac. Curabitur ut pulvinar neque, eu aliquam purus. Vestibulum imperdiet, orci eget molestie ultricies, est dui faucibus dui, et venenatis neque sem non lorem. In in massa condimentum, vulputate lacus vitae, posuere lorem. Nullam faucibus
  augue a dolor vestibulum, id efficitur augue aliquam. Fusce in ipsum aliquet, scelerisque augue ac, pretium urna. Nunc rutrum lacus vitae magna congue, vel finibus ligula sodales. Aenean vitae egestas lectus. Quisque ut pretium nunc. Curabitur id lectus
  est. Duis nulla elit, vestibulum vitae pulvinar sit amet, tristique ut leo. Curabitur finibus ipsum sit amet ante venenatis efficitur. Fusce molestie nibh nec nisi pretium finibus. Ut ullamcorper sapien sapien, ut dictum libero elementum et. Cras sapien
  augue, placerat vitae venenatis in, tempor sed enim. Nullam interdum, ante a pretium condimentum, ante lacus sollicitudin odio, at luctus lectus elit in mauris. Aenean a hendrerit neque, et porta ipsum. Maecenas tincidunt, eros eu auctor posuere, odio
  felis tincidunt leo, id pellentesque neque neque nec diam. Sed ac ante ac neque porta suscipit. Sed nec lacus ligula. Nunc maximus fermentum risus eget vehicula. Sed ac varius tortor. Fusce blandit mollis commodo. Quisque orci magna, consequat et orci
  at, consequat interdum arcu. Vestibulum vel iaculis magna, ut gravida enim. Nullam sollicitudin pharetra auctor. Mauris vulputate justo lorem, non aliquet elit cursus sed. Duis ultricies euismod diam, in rhoncus nisi auctor sit amet. Morbi dignissim
  fermentum sem, vel volutpat quam accumsan ut. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam quis lectus metus.
  <div>
```

`relative` :

```css
img,
span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
img {
  position:relative;
  margin-right:-100px;/* can be usefull*/
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img width="100" height="100" src="http://bestanimations.com/Animals/Reptiles/Dinosaurs/dinosaur-animated-gif-6.gif" />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer lobortis aliquam eros, sed vehicula eros rhoncus eu. Cras bibendum rhoncus nisl, non venenatis enim interdum vel. Mauris sodales risus ac ex suscipit ultricies. Duis neque purus, auctor
  non magna vel, euismod posuere metus. Fusce sit amet tortor quis felis consectetur iaculis. Phasellus risus nibh, finibus lacinia porta a, sagittis quis orci. Integer feugiat sit amet diam sit amet accumsan. In at finibus eros, vitae dictum eros. Donec
  dignissim tellus id dui auctor convallis. Donec in faucibus eros, at ultrices felis. Vivamus eros augue, suscipit a dignissim et, efficitur nec nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean iaculis consequat neque, et placerat
  tellus mollis ac. Curabitur ut pulvinar neque, eu aliquam purus. Vestibulum imperdiet, orci eget molestie ultricies, est dui faucibus dui, et venenatis neque sem non lorem. In in massa condimentum, vulputate lacus vitae, posuere lorem. Nullam faucibus
  augue a dolor vestibulum, id efficitur augue aliquam. Fusce in ipsum aliquet, scelerisque augue ac, pretium urna. Nunc rutrum lacus vitae magna congue, vel finibus ligula sodales. Aenean vitae egestas lectus. Quisque ut pretium nunc. Curabitur id lectus
  est. Duis nulla elit, vestibulum vitae pulvinar sit amet, tristique ut leo. Curabitur finibus ipsum sit amet ante venenatis efficitur. Fusce molestie nibh nec nisi pretium finibus. Ut ullamcorper sapien sapien, ut dictum libero elementum et. Cras sapien
  augue, placerat vitae venenatis in, tempor sed enim. Nullam interdum, ante a pretium condimentum, ante lacus sollicitudin odio, at luctus lectus elit in mauris. Aenean a hendrerit neque, et porta ipsum. Maecenas tincidunt, eros eu auctor posuere, odio
  felis tincidunt leo, id pellentesque neque neque nec diam. Sed ac ante ac neque porta suscipit. Sed nec lacus ligula. Nunc maximus fermentum risus eget vehicula. Sed ac varius tortor. Fusce blandit mollis commodo. Quisque orci magna, consequat et orci
  at, consequat interdum arcu. Vestibulum vel iaculis magna, ut gravida enim. Nullam sollicitudin pharetra auctor. Mauris vulputate justo lorem, non aliquet elit cursus sed. Duis ultricies euismod diam, in rhoncus nisi auctor sit amet. Morbi dignissim
  fermentum sem, vel volutpat quam accumsan ut. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam quis lectus metus.
  <div>
```

`fixed` (not the best):

```css
img,
span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
img {
  position:fixed;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img width="100" height="100" src="http://bestanimations.com/Animals/Reptiles/Dinosaurs/dinosaur-animated-gif-6.gif" />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer lobortis aliquam eros, sed vehicula eros rhoncus eu. Cras bibendum rhoncus nisl, non venenatis enim interdum vel. Mauris sodales risus ac ex suscipit ultricies. Duis neque purus, auctor
  non magna vel, euismod posuere metus. Fusce sit amet tortor quis felis consectetur iaculis. Phasellus risus nibh, finibus lacinia porta a, sagittis quis orci. Integer feugiat sit amet diam sit amet accumsan. In at finibus eros, vitae dictum eros. Donec
  dignissim tellus id dui auctor convallis. Donec in faucibus eros, at ultrices felis. Vivamus eros augue, suscipit a dignissim et, efficitur nec nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean iaculis consequat neque, et placerat
  tellus mollis ac. Curabitur ut pulvinar neque, eu aliquam purus. Vestibulum imperdiet, orci eget molestie ultricies, est dui faucibus dui, et venenatis neque sem non lorem. In in massa condimentum, vulputate lacus vitae, posuere lorem. Nullam faucibus
  augue a dolor vestibulum, id efficitur augue aliquam. Fusce in ipsum aliquet, scelerisque augue ac, pretium urna. Nunc rutrum lacus vitae magna congue, vel finibus ligula sodales. Aenean vitae egestas lectus. Quisque ut pretium nunc. Curabitur id lectus
  est. Duis nulla elit, vestibulum vitae pulvinar sit amet, tristique ut leo. Curabitur finibus ipsum sit amet ante venenatis efficitur. Fusce molestie nibh nec nisi pretium finibus. Ut ullamcorper sapien sapien, ut dictum libero elementum et. Cras sapien
  augue, placerat vitae venenatis in, tempor sed enim. Nullam interdum, ante a pretium condimentum, ante lacus sollicitudin odio, at luctus lectus elit in mauris. Aenean a hendrerit neque, et porta ipsum. Maecenas tincidunt, eros eu auctor posuere, odio
  felis tincidunt leo, id pellentesque neque neque nec diam. Sed ac ante ac neque porta suscipit. Sed nec lacus ligula. Nunc maximus fermentum risus eget vehicula. Sed ac varius tortor. Fusce blandit mollis commodo. Quisque orci magna, consequat et orci
  at, consequat interdum arcu. Vestibulum vel iaculis magna, ut gravida enim. Nullam sollicitudin pharetra auctor. Mauris vulputate justo lorem, non aliquet elit cursus sed. Duis ultricies euismod diam, in rhoncus nisi auctor sit amet. Morbi dignissim
  fermentum sem, vel volutpat quam accumsan ut. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam quis lectus metus.
  <div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:

```
img {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}
```

And if you want the text in front of the image, just change the z-index to -1

If you want to locate the image in a different place, add this:

```
img {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

and change it as you wish.

Comment: This great thanks, just having trouble centring it in the div. I did try top: 50%; and same with left. But that's not working

Comment: Running the snippet and going to 'full page', shows that the img is not centred on the div.

Comment: Added   vertically-align:middle; to the img style and that works now. Thanks